# Kendo editable treeview obserabale not getting the newly edited data of the node

Tags: kendo-ui, hierarchy, kendo-treeview, kendo-observable

I am using KendoUI Treeview control and binding it with observable view model. I want to edit the treeview items and should be updated in viewmodel.
I am using template having textbox inside. When I am editing it, I am not seeing updated value on change event.

Updated with the sample code link: http://dojo.telerik.com/oREGu/4
 when i edit the textbox i am expecting the item in the viewmodel be changed but is not